# Calculate year-on-year change in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, temporal

I have the following:

```
data = pd.DataFrame({'ID' : (1,2,1,2,1,2),
            'year': (1,1,2,2,3,3),
            'total_change' : (2,1,7,4,14,6)})
```

I want to calculate the absolute year-on-year change per row, which therefore needs to subtract the current year from the previous year (for the total_change variable.

I want the output to look as follows, where I have labelled the output column as annual_change:

```
output = pd.DataFrame({'ID' : (1,2,1,2,1,2),
            'year': (1,1,2,2,3,3),
            'total_change' : (2,1,7,4,14,6),
            'annual_change' : (2,1,5,3,7,2)})
```

Comment: You need `diff`? `data.groupby('ID').total_change.diff()`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
output = data.assign(annual_change=data.groupby("ID")['total_change'].apply(lambda x:x.diff().fillna(x)))
```

output:

```
   ID  total_change  year  annual_change
0   1             2     1            2.0
1   2             1     1            1.0
2   1             7     2            5.0
3   2             4     2            3.0
4   1            14     3            7.0
5   2             6     3            2.0
```